# azure sdk for net login is takes too long

Tags: azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I am using [Fluent Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Fluent) to develop a web app which can create a sql server on azure. The console app works great but when I implement the code to a web api it stuck in authentication step. I'm sure about the credentials which are true and I have a Service Principal.

```
// Authenticate
var credentials = new AzureCredentials(new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation { ClientId = ClientId, ClientSecret = Password }, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var azure = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscription();
```

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it that will help more communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also can repro it on my side. I try to debug it with following code and add **quick watch** for `azureauth.WithDefaultSubscription()`, then get value **The function evaluation requires all threads to run**. So I guess that it may run some threads that WebAPI can't handle.

```
  var azureauth = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials);

  azureauth.WithDefaultSubscription()
```

[image]

Please have a try to use following code to use specified subscriptionId as workaround. It works correctly on my side.

var azure = `Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription("subscriptionId");`

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, I decided to move on the [Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/) beacuse I saw that it works great.

Comment: As your mention Azure Rest API should work. But  for you mentioned using Azure SDK , I think `Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription("subscriptionId")` it also works well;